# Install a specific old package with dependencies

Tags: debian, repository, dependencies, snapshot

I need to install a specific version of tomcat (**6.0.16**) using `apt-get install` **with dependencies** from an old Debian repository.

Old repositories can be found at: `http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/[date]/...`

However there is a lot of repositories. How can I easily find the good one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general idea is to go to [the snapshot site](http://snapshot.debian.org/) and enter the source or binary package name in the search fields on the left-hand side.

For `tomcat6` this will lead to http://snapshot.debian.org/package/tomcat6/ which lists the available snapshots of the `tomcat6` source package. You'll find version 6.0.16-1 on http://snapshot.debian.org/package/tomcat6/6.0.16-1/ which then leads to http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20080529T000000Z/pool/main/t/tomcat6/ (look for "/pool" links). That probably won't have what you're after though because the complete Tomcat 6 package was only available starting with version 6.0.18-1; you'll find that on http://snapshot.debian.org/package/tomcat6/6.0.18-1/ which will lead you to http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20090221T225736Z/pool/main/t/tomcat6/ (which also has 6.0.18-2, which is the same as 6.0.18-1, only the target distibution changed).

So if you really specifically need version 6.0.16, you're out of luck as far as finding a Debian package is concerned... There was a complete package in Ubuntu at some point, version 6.0.16-1ubuntu1, but that was replaced by 6.0.18 which is the oldest remaining package in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tomcat6/. You could always check out the [Ubuntu source repository](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat6) and rebuild 6.0.16 from there...